# iMacro: test resulting URL

Tags: automation, imacros

Using iMacro (chrome extension), I would like to automate an action on a website:

1. check a checkbox (conditions)
2. click button (submit)
3. then compare the resulting url to a string

   if true ==> restart script from beginning
   if false ==> show a popup message (or anything else Alerting the user)

I started from here after recording steps 1 and 2 which works fine and can run in loop

```
VERSION BUILD=8350307 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=http://websitew.com/5421/0
REFRESH
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://websitew.com/5421/0#
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:FormBookingCreate ATTR=ID:condition CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:FormBookingCreate ATTR=NAME:nextButton
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:FormBookingCreate ATTR=NAME:finishButton
```

Further, it doesn't accept **if** satement, and I don't know how to inform the user with some kind of messagebox or alert

```
SET current {{!URLCURRENT}}

#if current = "http://websitew.com/5421/0" then
MsgBox "OK!"
else
   """start from the beginning """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution for the Chrome 'iMacros' extension:

```
' here your code with the 1st and 2nd steps '

SET S EVAL("('{{!URLCURRENT}}' == 'http://websitew.com/5421/0') ? 'alert(\"OK!\");' : 'undefined';")
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}

' uncomment the line below to stop your macro after a message box '
'SET E EVAL("('{{S}}' == 'undefined') ? '' : MacroError('STOP!');")
```

Comment: Thanks Shugar. It does the job. Now I have a good start to learn more.